# How to find out that an Oracle Table Partition is a System Generated Partition?

Tags: oracle, catalog

Am creating an Oracle HASH Table Partitions by using the below query

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(50))
  PARTITION BY HASH (ID) 
  PARTITIONS 25
STORE IN (Tablespace1);
```

Which Creates 25 HASH table partitions and also, the Database generates the 25 Unique partition names like SYS_P122, SYS_P123, SYS_P124... and so on for the partitions. Is there a way to find out this Partition lets say SYS_P123 is a system generated Partition name with the help of Oracle Catalog tables.
With the below link
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2096.htm#REFRN20281
I could find the Oracle Table Partition information, but this catalog table does not have any value to say that the give Table Partition is a system generate or not. Is there any way to find out the given table partition name is system generated ?

Am using Oracle version 10 and 11.

Thanks,
Ravi,

Comment: what is a *not* system generated hash partition ?

Comment: It seems that system generated partition names simply start SYS_ and end with a series of digits. Maybe you just need to pattern match with a regexp.

Comment: @ haki... we can specify the name of the partition also by using the below query CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(50))
 PARTITION BY HASH (ID) 

(PARTITION "P1" TABLESPACE "Tablespace1",
 PARTITION "P2" TABLESPACE "Tablespace1",
 PARTITION "P3" TABLESPACE "Tablespace2");   where P1, P2, P3 are the partition names given by the User. These are the two different ways of creating partitions.

Comment: @ David.... Oracle also allows any one to create a Partition name with SYS_ followed by a number so this way is not fool proof way. Was expecting a column in catalog table to know this value.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The generated column in dba_objects gives the information.
Run the following query - 
select owner, object_name, subobject_name, generated from all_objects where object_name = 'TABLE1' and object_type = 'TABLE PARTITION';

View the description for the 'generated' column in the following link - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1145.htm#REFRN20146